# wrap image tags with an anchor tags by jQuery

Tags: jquery

My Html structure is following:

```
<div class="content">
<img alt="" src="a.png" height="400" width="400">
<a href="https:www.google.com" class="avatar" ></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
<img alt="" src="b.png" height="400" width="400">
<a href="https:www.yahoo.com" class="avatar" ></a>
</div>
```

I want to wrap the anchor tag around the image tag by jquery,so my final result would be:

```
<div class="content">
<a href="https:www.google.com" class="avatar" >
<img alt="" src="a.png" height="400" width="400">
</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
<a href="https:www.yahoo.com" class="avatar" >
<img alt="" src="b.png" height="400" width="400">
</a>
</div>
```

What's the easiest way of doing this with jQuery?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you end up with the first structure in the first place? And what have you tried?

Comment: Can you answer putvande's question, how did you get this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the image and append it to the anchor tag like so:

```
jQuery('img').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).next('a'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usucw6dt/)

Answer (score 1):

Consider following:

```
$('.content img').each(function() {
    $(this).next('a').wrapInner($(this));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkv3aLty/1/)

---

```
$('.content img').each(function() {
   $(this).next('a').html($(this).clone());
   $(this).remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkv3aLty/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.content > img').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);

   //Clone the image and store it in a variable
   var img = that.clone();

   //Select the anchor next to each image and append the cloned image
   that.next('a').html(img);

   //Remove the original image
   that.remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use the `.wrap()` function. It's pretty quick and simple

```
$("content img").each(function(el, i){
   var a = $(this).next().clone();
   $(this).next().remove();
   $(this).wrap(a);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/